# boot2docker can't access the outside world

Tags: ruby, networking, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

On OSX, through boot2docker, I have a ruby on rails app running in a docker container.

However, it can't seem to access third party API's.

The code below works outside of a docker container, but not inside:

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?site=stackoverflow')
```

When run from inside a docker container the request timeouts with:

```
SocketError: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
```

At this point I think the problem might be with the boot2docker setup, as if do:

```
boot2docker ssh
ping stackexchange.com
```

then it timeouts.

I am using OSX 10.10.3, boot2docker 1.50, and docker-compose

Comment: Does a `docker search hello-world` work? Are you behind a proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more digging I found an issue on Github, installing boot2docker via brew was the problem.

I uninstalled, via brew, rebooted and installed directly from http://boot2docker.io/ . This appears to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Secondary: If your Mac loses connection / goes to sleep then you will need to restart boot2docker